# How to close or disable base authentication popup in WebDriver(FirefoxDriver) test

Tags: java, integration-testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using WebDriver for testing my application, but some pages are trying to get resources from another server, which requires authentication. I don't need that resources for my test and I don't have credentials as far.
When popup appears, it stops test run.

I tried to close popup using `webDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` but obviously it's not alert.

I tried also to disable popup using firefox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("capability.policy.policynames", "strict") ;
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.strict.sites",  "http://localhost:9000") ;
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.strict.Window.alert", "noAccess") ;
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.strict.Window.confirm", "noAccess") ;
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.strict.Window.prompt", "noAccess") ;
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think web driver was designed with the above intent in mind and I dont see any such api being provided in the near future too.. They would want to test to behave exactly how a human would see the page.

Having said that you have control over the site that you are running the test against. cant you block these resources yourself probably be using some configuration setting that doesnt load the resource when the flag in the configuration is set to true.

The setting might be something like IsSeleniumInstance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should receive that credentials in nearest future, and it's meaningless to perform additional functionality to disable such resources as images for a test because it could be tested in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue for Selenium: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=34
There is a fix for Firefox, but I don't believe it is included in any of the current releases.  The fix still needs to be implemented for other supported browsers.